# SWT open source applications gallery?

Tags: java, swt, jface

I'm new to SWT/JFace. I would like to know if someone could indicate real world apllications based on SWT/Jface but not on Eclipse RCP. I can see lot of examples (come of them very professional) of RCP based apps, but nothing about SWT/Jface standalone.
I would like to start to develop an utility app with these libraries (instead of Swing), and a well done, commerical quality, example application would help a lot to start the right way...

Thanks a lot,
Giovanni

Answer (score 2):

See a list of real-world SWT applications [here](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/community.php).

I'm working on [Zekr](http://zekr.org/), which is only based on SWT (neither RPC nor JFace).

Comment: Thanks Mohsen, it looks very nice and it can be of help for me to startup with SWT!